# Fix for stsadm export: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: 2007, migration, export, stsadm, content-deployment

**Current Issue:**

When performing an export on a web I get the following error:

> STSADM.EXE : An item with the same key has already been added.

I have tried checking in and checking out the file. But soon after I [read](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/949cf082-3727-4ed7-bef7-f3fbc383871a) changing the ID even will not help so I did not continue with this. Also, I get this error on 4 seperate sibling subwebs that I attempt. How can I fix this issue?

**Overall Goal**

I am trying to move a 200+gb web (and subs) from one site collection to another. This web includes around 30 subwebs at various levels. Some which are Publishing some which are not.
I did not use Backup/Import because I [read](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441%28v=office.12%29.aspx) you cannot do it when a site collection is >15gb. Please note that although I am trying to take a web, it is at level 2 so I am not opposed to copying the entire site collection.
I hope to use powershell/visual studio/MS tools. If there is a db level solution that works as well.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out only exporting the LastMajorandMinor versions as opposed to all solved this.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know if your web is greater than 25 MB it will not work.
What version of SHarePoint are u using? with what Service Pack.

There is other way is to use SPD backup and restore. I have tried this one when export/import stsadm fails and it will work fine.

Again you need to consider the limitation of export and import cmd when you moving big chunck.

There are few other utilities available like 
Gary Lapointe stsadm cmd,
spcontent deployment tool.

Let me know how you go with SPD backup/restore.

Comment: This is SP 2007 not sure the service pack but I would assume the latest. Also I did not use backup/restore because as tagged in my question MS specifically limits to 15gb where as export/import lists no limit.

Comment: I did a deep dive into Gary Lapointe's stsadm helper export and all the way at the end we end up running the same base stsadm command. :)

Comment: There is limit no such a limit of 15 gb for backup/restore command. It operational limitation is 50 gb as it takes a long time to restore the backup and it times up. 15 gb will not be a limitation for stsadm -o backup/restore command based on my experience.

So Gary Lapointe cmd will work for you?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I am well aware that this thing wont crash or give me a error message when going past 15gb but i'd rather follow MS guidance in a production environment. It would be one thing if this was only test than I wouldn't care if it ran for 2days.